# Error when using AJAX whit response.getWriter()

Tags: ajax

Hello and thank for your time. I have a problem with my response.getWriter.write

Here is my jsp code

enter code here

```
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
    var form = $('#form-registrazione');
            form.submit(function ()  {
                $.ajax({
                    type:'post',
                    url: 'utente',
                    data: form.serialize(),
                    success:function (data) {
                        var result = data;
                        if(result == "usernameEsistente"){
                            alert("IL PENE");
                            $('#errore').html("NON VA BENE");
                        }
                        if(result == "vabene"){
                            window.location.replace("/index.jsp");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }   
    </script>
```

and in my servlet "utente" I have this code portion:

```
            if(model.checkUsername(username)){
                    Utente utente = new Utente();
                    utente.setUser(username);
                    utente.setPass(password);
                    utente.setTipo("Cliente");

                    model.doSaveNewAccount(utente); 
                    response.getWriter().write("vabene");
                }
                else{
                    response.getWriter().write("usernameEsistente");
                }
```

the problem is, the response.getWriter().write() overwrite the whole page
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XB64J.jpg

I don't understand why it stays in the servlet page, and does not return in the jsp page where ajax is.